# Display WordPress CPT taxonomy terms in loops

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm having a hard time getting the right result when I try building loops for WordPress. I haven't really understood the mechanism behind it yet.

- I have a custom post type registered with Toolset called "Produkter"
  (products)
- In "Produkter" I have a taxonomy called "Produktkategori" (product
  categories).
- In "Produktkategori" I have a couple of parent terms with multiple children. So two levels of terms.

I want to create 2 loop templates. The first needs to display only the parent terms name and term image, and the other the term children. I managed to create the loop displaying the children, but I can't figure out to create the one for the parent, without displaying the children items.

This is the working displaying the children terms:

```html
<div class="kategori-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <h1 class="side-overskrift">Gulve</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="600">
        <p>Overordnet beskrivelse af undergulve</p>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="600">
                <div class="row">

             <?php
             $_terms = $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'produktkategori');

             foreach ($_terms as $term) :

                 $term_slug = $term->slug;
                 $_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                             'post_type'         => '',
                             'posts_per_page'    => 200, //important for a PHP memory limit warning
                             'tax_query' => array(
                                 array(
                                     'taxonomy' => 'produktkategori',
                                     'field'    => 'slug',
                                     'terms'    => 'gulve',
                         'order'    => 'ASC',
                                 ),
                             ),
                         ));

                 if( $_posts->have_posts() ) :
                     while ( $_posts->have_posts() ) : $_posts->the_post();
                     ?>
                         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 kategori-container">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="kategori-billede"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?></img></a>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="kategori-navn"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                         </div>
                     <?php
                     endwhile;

                 endif;
                 wp_reset_postdata();

             endforeach;
             ?>
                        </div></div>

              </div>

            </div>
```

In the parent loop I want to show the parent terms of the taxonomy "produktkategori", without also showing the children's content. How can I achieve that? I can't find the right solution.

Comment: Is it really necessary to edit the language of a question i wonder?

Comment: It's pretty normal here, Webmaster. The reason for it is that questions are kept forever, with the hope that the "curated" set of Q&A are useful for thousands of readers and not just the original author.